# axio. to get the data in a different file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise

I hope you can help me.

I'm trying to get a response from an API and use that information in another file.

I have 3 files:

**api.jsx**

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const api = (url, data) => {

    const { path, method } = url;

    let result ={};
    axios({
            method: method,
            url: path,
            data: data
        })
        .then(res => {

            result = res.data;
            console.log(res.data);   
        })        
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
    return result;
};
```

**url.jsx**

```
    export const URL = {
    users:
        {
            getAllUsers: { path:'/users', method: 'post'},
            login: { path:'/login', method: 'post'},
            register: { path:'/register', method: 'post'},
            version: { path:'/', method: 'get'},
        }

}
```

**app.js** (within the render)

```
    const data = {
      email: 'hello@world.com',
      password: '12345',
      };

    let result = api(URL.users.login, data);

    console.log(result);
```

In the api file i get the proper response but in the react component no. I am aware that It's a problem of sync as i get first the console of app.jsx and later on the console of the api.jsx but i would like to respect the current structure or make something similar.

Any idea how to fix this without many changes?

PS. sorry about the mess. I tried to highlight all the code but for some reason it is not working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to return a `Promise` in api.jsx

`api.jsx`

```js
export const api = (url, data) => {
  const { path, method } = url
  return axios({ // the axios call returns a promise because of its .then; you can just return it
    method: method,
    url: path,
    data: data
  })
  .then(res => {
    return res.data;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
  })
}
```